# Best case for sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Given this sorting algorithm:

```
Sort(A, n):
    if (n == 1)
     return
    isSorted = true
    for i=1 to n-1 do:
        if (A[i] > A[i+1]):
            isSorted = false
            temp = A[i]
            A[i] = A[i+1]
            A[i+1] = temp
    end for
    if (isSorted)
         return
    else
         Sort(A, n-1)
```

I'm required to find the upper bound for the best case.
My question is - is the best case considered when the array length is 1? Or when the array is already sorted and then the loop runs only once? Or both cases?

Also, I need to find a recursive formula for the worst case.
I got to this formula:

if n $\neq1$
$F(n) = F(n-1) + n - 1$
else
F(n) = 1

Is it correct?

Comment: There is no asymptotic analysis unless at least one aspect of input is not limited.

Comment: @greybeard Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The bounding of function growth is used in characterising algorithm complexity for some measure of problem size growing boundlessly - including *best case* analysis. *Input size 1* simply isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

We usually measure the running time of algorithm as a function of the length of the input.

For example, when we say that an algorithm runs in time $O(n\log n)$, what we mean is:

- For every input of length $n$, the algorithm runs in time $O(n\log n)$.

This is an example of worst-case complexity. In your case, you are looking for a function $T(n)$ which satisfies the following:

- For every input of length $n$, the algorithm runs in time *at least* $T(n)$.
- Furthermore, for each $n$ there exists an input of length $n$ on which the algorithm runs in time $T(n)$.

To answer your particular questions: the answer should be a function of $n$; and we are looking for the "best-case scenario" of the algorithm for each input length $n$. Whether this best-case scenario is the one you said or not, depends on the algorithm. There might be algorithms for which your best-case scenario is actually a worst-case input (we can construct such algorithms artificially).

Comment: Am I supposed to count number of comparisons?

Comment: In your post, you say that you're required "to find the upper bound for the best case". You never say what is being upper-bounded – time, number of comparisons, or any other complexity measure. Only you (or the person who set the question) can know the answer.

Comment: Got it, so I need to ask for a clarification. Thank you